# Best way to check all partners of a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a really common problem, and I hate trying to solve this by just writing all the possible combinations, so what's the best way to do it?
For example:
x = [[['0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '0']], [['0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '0']], [['0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0'], ['1', '1', '0']]]

so x[i][j][k] can all be accessed etc. Lets say I want to find x[1][1][1]'s partners, what is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is dull with explanation on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what error/problem you encounter. Furthermore, it doesn't look like you made any kind of effort on researching the topic, like you said "really common problem".

Assuming "partner" means neighbor/adjacent element you can do the following:
Lets take a 2D array as a simple example, the numbers on top and on the side symbolize the rows and columns, the '-' and 'X' are values int the array.

```
  0  1  2  3
0 -  X  -  X
1 -  -  X  X
2 X  X  -  X
3 -  -  -  -
```

Lets say you want to find the adjacent addresses in the array to arr[1][1] = '-'.
All you'll have to do is check, if you add or decrease the placement by one in the row or column, will it overflow the array (For example: does row 2 exist in the array, if so then it's adjacent is arr[2][1]). You will have to do this by increasing and decreasing the value by one for each row/column(/another dimension):

```
arr[1][0]
arr[1][2]
arr[0][1]
arr[2][1]
```

They all exist in the array that it's row spans from 0-3 and its columns from 0-3.

**Bonus:** If you would like to to find the value of adjacent elements all you'll have to do is ask to display the values of the existing adjacent elements (call arr[1][0]).

There are plenty more methods and tricks on the internet and especially in Stack Overflow. Check this link, might give you some ideas: [2d array, all values are adjacent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322347/2d-array-all-values-are-adjacent)

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, and i understand this solution because its what i see everytime i look this up. I was hoping that there was some better way to do this instead of placing all of the values in a whole, index +- 1 idea.

Comment: If you are doing this action multiple times, you can just make a function out of it or even a class that can scan different kinds of things in different sized arrays.